Unable to Bypass "Verify you are human" Cloudflare CAPTCHA using Selenium in Firefox
I'm trying to automate a login process on the ChatGPT website using Selenium with Firefox, but I'm stuck at the Cloudflare CAPTCHA ("Verify you are human") page. I’ve tried a few different configurations, including using a fake user agent and disabling WebDriver flags, but I can't seem to bypass this verification.
Here's the code I’m currently using:
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

MAIL = "CHATGPTEMAIL"
PASSWORD = "CHATGPTPASSWORD"
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={UserAgent().random}")
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=./")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)  # Disable WebDriver flag
options.set_preference("useAutomationExtension", False)  # Avoid using automation extension
options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "YourRandomUserAgentHere")  # Custom User-Agent

options.add_argument("--headless")  # Optional: run in headless mode
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

browser.get('https://chat.openai.com/auth/login')
sleep(4)

# Try clicking the first button to proceed with login
inputElements = browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "button")
inputElements[0].click()
sleep(3)

# Enter email
mail = browser.find_elements(By.NAME,"email")[0]
mail.send_keys(MAIL)

# Click the next button
btn = browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "button")[0]
btn.click()

# Enter password
password = browser.find_elements(By.NAME,"password")[0]
password.send_keys(PASSWORD)
sleep(2)

browser.quit()


Things I have tried:
Using different User Agents with the fake_useragent library.
Disabling the dom.webdriver.enabled and useAutomationExtension flags.
Running Firefox in headless mode.
Adding a custom User-Agent string directly.
Questions:
Is there any workaround to bypass the Cloudflare CAPTCHA with Selenium?
Has anyone successfully automated the login process for ChatGPT or other sites protected by Cloudflare using Selenium?
Are there any specific configurations for Firefox that might help with this?
Any advice on how to bypass or handle this CAPTCHA would be greatly appreciated!
